# About python's function and a possible solution in java code

Tags: java, python

I'm a java developer. I was using a service (not written by me) in Python, and now this is not available anymore.

I have the source code and I need to covert a part of it in Java. Can you please help me with this two lines of code?

```
name = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', unicode(name, 'utf_8', errors='ignore')).encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
name = re.sub('[^a-z0-9]', '', name.replace('&', 'and').replace('+', 'plus').replace('*', 'star').lower()
```

there is an import of these packages at the very beginning:

```
import os, re, unicodedata
```

As far as I understood the String "name" is normalized using "Normalization Form Compatibility Composition", and for that I found the corresponding Java function:

```
String name="Test";
name = Normalizer.normalize(name, Normalizer.Form.NFKD);
```

But I have no idea how to translate the second line: I searched for the definition of re.sub and I found this:

> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping
>   occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl. If the
>   pattern isn’t found, string is returned unchanged. repl can be a
>   string or a function; if it is a string, any backslash escapes in it
>   are processed. That is, \n is converted to a single newline character,
>   \r is converted to a carriage return, and so forth. Unknown escapes
>   such as \j are left alone. Backreferences, such as \6, are replaced
>   with the substring matched by group 6 in the pattern.

But I didn't understand what it means...

**The best would be to have also the vice versa:** So from a normalized and altered string get the original.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If translating is too hard, you could always execute the python in a new process and store the output (assuming speed isn't a priority).